# how to use Apache at my Android App

Tags: android, apache, xampp

I want to read and update data from server (using Apache) to my Android App.
I`m new at the Apache part.can anyone give me a guide for this kind of operation? I already download "XAMPP", and my main goal is to read a JSON into my App, but I believe I can manage also with php .

I know that this is general question but I don't understand at this subject.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the most basic way is to make sure your web server is listening on an open port(usually 80). in your android app send a request to your webserver (url request). on your server hava a script that echos or prints JSON data...

Comment: thanks @user1290942, so there is a way to generate a Json code from php?

Comment: `<?php echo '{"fname":"joe","lname":"docker","height":"6'2"}'; ?>` lets say this was index.php just send a request to xx.x.x.xxx/index.php and it will return the JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Apache is a web server. You need to connect to it using HTTP. There is an `HttpClient` and other ways to get http server data, as long as you have a network connection.